# Collecting BBC News data to analyze, using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to collect BBC news data based on some keywords, and want to collect it in the descending order of date (sorted with date). However, I only see the data in the order of relevance. Is there a way to collect data sorted with date ?

Below is the link I am using to get the data. https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=Harvard+student&sa_f=search-product&scope=

Such options are available in other website, but I would like to use the data of BBC News.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried up to now?

Comment: Why don't you scrape all the posts and sort them by date? It's a silly idea but it works if there is no date interval.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried web scrapping the articles by relevance (ran the code to web scrap few pages), but number of pages are huge, and I just want the data from 2015 - 2018. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one of example how you can get all news sorted by descending date using javascript, return list of news(li) elements:

```
sortedNews = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll(".search-results.results li")].map(e=>{if (e.querySelector("time")!=null) return e;}).filter(function (el) {return el != null;}).sort(function (a, b) { return a.querySelector("time").dateTime < b.querySelector("time").dateTime ? 1 : -1;});')
for news in sortedNews:
    print(news.find_element_by_css_selector("li h1").text);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. Can you please suggest how to embed this code in a python program? 
And [...document.querySelectorAll -- what do dots represent here?

Comment: It's javascript code return array to be able use filter and sort methods. Try it and give feed if it works.

Comment: Thank you. I just added your code in my code. However, I am not sure how to refer to the variable "sortedNews". I am relatively new to selenium. Please let me know how to use this variable to get the news sorted by date

Comment: `code  driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\project\IEDriverServer")

driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=harvard+university")
sortedNews = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll(".search-results.results li")].map(e=>{if (e.querySelector("time")!=null) return e;}).filter(function (el) {return el != null;}).sort(function (a, b) { return a.querySelector("time").dateTime < b.querySelector("time").dateTime ? 1 : -1;});')   
s1="""//*[@id="search-container"]/div[3]/div/div/h3/a"""
head = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(s1)`

Comment: Please check my answer update. I added loop to print news titles.

Comment: Thank you !!! It makes some sense to me now.. Basically, you are fetching the reference of all the news sorted by date, storing in "sortedNews", and fetching it one by one. correct me if i am wrong
However, I have some confusion as I did not understand the query you wrote. I am trying to access only those news which have "students " and "harvard" in its text; where can we put these keywords to filter the news before fetching them?

Comment: You can search for harvard and students like you did in your question and then use code I provide. I use JavaScript and you can modify it or filter using python. My code give you all news you without advertisings.